# Efficient way to use Bull Queue in Nestjs

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, bull, bull-queue

I'm integrating Bull Queue for my email service which I'm using in multiple modules. But after injecting Queue in the email.service.ts file, I'm getting dependency errors like the below for all modules where I was using this service.

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.forRoot({}),
  ],
  exports: [BullModule],
})
```

email.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.registerQueue({
      name: 'email',
    }),
  ],
  providers: [EmailService, EmailConsumer],
  exports: [EmailService],
})
```

email.service.ts

```
constructor(@InjectQueue('email') private readonly emailQueue: Queue) {}
```

[image: Dependency Error]

auth.module.ts (before error)

```
@Module({
  imports: [JwtModule.register({})],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    ...authProviders,
  ],
})
```

auth.module.ts (after resolving error)

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.register({}),
    BullModule.registerQueue({
      name: 'email',
    })
],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    ...authProviders,
  ],
})
```

I resolved this error by registering a queue in every module file (10-15 in my case) as I did in email.module.ts. but I think there must be an efficient way to do this. Instead of copy-pasting code in every module.

Comment: can you provide your auth.module file?